# Is it possible to program free will?

Tags: free-will

In any computational environment(digital,neural,analog or quantum mechanical) is it possible to write or construct a program which can be construed as free will?

Comment: Free will is a very slippery issue... According to some, there is no [free will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/freewill/#3.3).

Comment: i upvoted because an answer seems relevant

Comment: to questions about what free will is, i mean, could shed some insight into various questions about it, disappointed in the unhelpful downvote

Comment: There are different notions of free will (see the link given by Mauro ALLEGRANZA) and there are different ideas of what qualifies as programming (e.g., do AI systems count as programs, or do you only consider explicitly programmed systems?) - as such, this question is not really answerable without more context.

Comment: @Keelan seems Dheeraj means AI on the grounds that i am anyway not sure what "explicitly programmed systems" could even mean in this context? here to learn mind Keelan :)

Comment: "Can be construed" by whom? "Construct a program" how? Saberhagen describes robots called [berserkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_(Saberhagen)) who make decisions using computers attached to random number generators. Does this qualify? I agree with Keelan, to make the question answerable some constraints on what counts as "free will" and "program" are needed. And once those are specified I suspect the question will answer itself.

Comment: "Is it possible to construct a complex chemical reaction with free will?"  Evidently, yes... so doing the same with a computer doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is scientific speculation

Comment: Produce a child

Comment: @Dave smart answer but while reproducing are writing or constructing free will with full awareness ? No

Comment: Determinism vs free will? I don’t think we have an answer to that. We don’t know how in-depth our minds are. If there are a vast number of variables, or unlimited

Comment: There are unlimited number of variables.

Comment: Unlimited? Your brain must be huge

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is simple based on the wording;

"construct a program which can be **construed** as free will"

and the answer is yes. Whether or not free will actually exists is irrelevant considering that many people have construed our own existences as having free will. The chess playing computer has free will in the sense that it chooses what moves to make based on input.

Humans, which we'll say have free will for the sake of comparison, are also limited by knowledge/information but make similar decisions.

It is conceivable that as technology grows, and things like google's deep mind improve, we'll have programs that learn information and make decisions based on that information ultimately writing their own programming the way a human defines themselves and builds character from experience. But is it free will, it can be **construed** as such a thing, but if you break even our decisions down to reactions in our neural pathways and the deterministic behavior of atoms, there may be no other way to declare free will.

Comment: "The chess playing computer has free will in the sense that it chooses what moves to make based on input "... well, no. That's sort of the opposite of free will. The chess computer must make a specific move given any input. Unless you create one that makes random moves, though I'm guessing it wouldn't play very well (would make an interesting experiment though).

Comment: @barrycarter I agree with what you said about the alternative except that it cannot make "random moves" based on the input from a random number generator.  That is still determinism.  The program's answer has to be probabilistic and run on a quantum computer, assuming such provides probabilistic output.

Answer (score 5):

No. First consider what we mean by free will.

One sense of free will is that with enough information it is possible to predict every choice the machine, let's call it Mike, makes. There are two major problems predicting what Mike will choose, chaos and quantum physics. If the universe were perfectly deterministic, then we could theoretically build a machine to predict Mike's choices. Chaos theory introduces the problem of initial conditions, that we have to have infinite information to predict Mike's choice. Quantum physics introduces Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, that it's not even possible to know everything about Mike's state at any point in time.

From this one might gather that free will is therefore true, but this is incorrect. Just because it is impossible to know the exact state of Mike at any point in time does not mean that there is not an exact state of Mike at any point in time. However you want to see mike, as a quantum system, a chaotic system, or a classical system, his choices are a product of events in that system. To claim free will is to say that somehow Mike is able to transcend that system.

That being said, Mike is a decision making machine, just like us humans. Because at some level the decision making process is opaque to all observers within the system, Mike is like a black box. Because of this fact, what is the practical difference between Mike and a machine that actually has free will?

Claiming free will exists is the same as claiming souls exist, because they are both outside the realm of physics. However, you could claim that Mike does have free will, or a soul, and no one would be able to disprove you. The only way to "build" a machine with true free will would be to do so outside of the boundaries of science.

Comment: "his choices are a product of events in that system". I think the issue here is: since the events in the system are random, how do we know that the events are a product of his choices? In other words, the randomness of quantum mechanics may be an artifact of free will. Example: we are free to observe which of two paths a particle may take-- quantum mechanics insures the particle takes that path.

Comment: @barrycarter Consider the various interpretations of quantum physics. In the Many Worlds interpretation every possibility does obtain, so free will makes no sense. Other interpretations such as De Broglie-Bohm are entirely deterministic. Quantum information theories claim that there is no objective state of the system, so I don't see how to connect free will, but maybe it's possible. In fact, there are hardly any interpretations that allow for free will.

Comment: @AndyPBJ Given our own free will and Conway-Kochen's free will theorem, one could claim that a quantum system has libertarian free will.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3286.pdf A program using a quantum computer could have free will based on what quantum particles have.  I haven't used these, but if the results of such quantum computers require that we have only a probability of getting a correct answer then I could see these programs as illustrating libertarian free will.

Comment: You assume a libertarian free will picture, not even recognising compatibilism

Answer (score 3):

The closest you could is to use a [true quantum mechanical random number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator#Quantum_random_properties) generator, and base the program's actions off that. If quantum mechanics is correct in saying the universe is inherently random, the program's actions could not be predicted in advance, and would thus constitute a form of "free will".

Of course, that doesn't mean the program (or machine running the program) has free will any more than a rock has free will, but, since you can't predict its actions, it can at least give the *illusion* of free will, even though it's running a fixed algorithm.

There are several methods to generate psuedo-random numbers and sites like https://www.random.org/ use atmospheric noise to generate high quality random numbers, but, if you accept that atmospheric noise is predictable (ie, it measures something "large" enough that quantum randomness "averages out"), then your program's actions could still *theoretically* be predictable.

By using a true quantum random number generator, your machine/program's actions would be unpredictable, even in theory.

NOTE: google suggests there are some sites which offer true quantum-level random numbers and that true quantum-level random number generators (hardware) are available. I did not explore either deeply.

Comment: But wouldn't it give the *illusion of lack of control* rather than free will?

Comment: Since the OP mentioned programming, I was thinking free will as opposed to predictable actions (which most programs have, or at least should have). You're saying that simulating free will also requires the machine act in a consistent (thought not entirely predictable) way that appears to cater to its best interests?

Comment: I think I get your point—kind of like a Turing machine, such that an outsider can't tell the difference.

Comment: @PédeLeão Yes, but you make a good point too. Free will isn't just about unpredictability. It's also about what an entity "wants". So, you'd have to simulate desire and tilt the probabilities in favor of obtaining that desire, so the actions wouldn't be completely random, but without going to the Pavlov's dogs extreme.

Comment: @barrycarter You could look at the output of a random number generator as environmental input.  The program's response to it, like any other input, has to show free will.  It would have to be able to generate a state that is not completely explained by anything coming before this state.  One way to simulate the illusion of free will is to have a broken or buggy program, but that only stimulates free will.

Answer (score 0):

Something I wrote yesterday: Choice can be defined as "some resulting brain signals after options are percieved consciously, until options have been chosen". If options are not chosen, the choice process did not conclude, or was cancelled at some point and choice disappeared.

A robot with some kind of will would have to have a consciousness and be able to perceive options, and impressions of choice. The "freedom" in free will could reasonably be the impression of "being able to choose what I want", so the consciousness would then need to be able to perceive the impression of self and want.

So can one program such a conscioussness into a robot, so that it expresses free will? Only if programmable consciousness-creating components can be built, which is unknown as far as I know. Alternatively one could argue that free will doesn't exist other than in the form of sentences belonging to a set, and that if something generates such sentences, it has free will.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd say it would be fairly simple to simulate the function of free will.

Neurons are all about thresholds to activate, often requiring multiple inputs to trigger. Taking consciousness as a global workspace, which things enter when our automated out-of-consciousness subroutines fail, we can picture conscious awareness as triggered by things behaving unexpectedly.

Using the strange-loop model of self awareness, we can see a global workspace that contains a token representing itself, which can be updated based on projected decisions, we have a system which can make choices based on it's entire knowledge, including a sense of what kind of self to become.

Still deterministic, but it's obvious decision making by an agent using a model of itself, can create feedback, amplifying unexpected behaviours, and stabilising for useful traits. Highly valuable for systems which are evolving in a selection landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by free will you are referring to the ability to make decisions, I would say no.

Decision-making is a *mental* process that generates *knowledge* about what the decider is about to do. No program can ever process or understand knowledge, let alone generate *new* knowledge.

Machines don't understand or know anything, they want nothing, they have no opinions about anything, they have no agenda, no plans for the future. They only do what people decide they should do.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody knows if people have free will. They usually do what’s good for them, but not always. They can be predictable, like not crossing the street when a lorry approaches at high speed. They can be unpredictable at other times, being spontaneous or just idiotic. But the background to all this is that the human brain and it’s function are so complex that we can’t predict it. We may be deterministic, or we may have free will. (Quantum physics can make is unpredictable, but that’s not free will).

Now imagine a computer, advanced enough to be equally capable as a human brain, with the means to express itself and act. No, you can’t program it to have free will. If it’s programmed, it’s not free will. You can’t program it to be happy or sad, it’s not real.

What we *might* be able to do is to create a machine that has the same potential as a newborn human, and let it develop. It may end up the same as a human, with us unable to determine if it has free will or not.

Comment: Humans have been 'programmed' by evolution & experiences. Surely if a computer was fully as complex as a human brain, you could put a functional copy of a human brain on it?